# Powerbuilder Drop down datawindow filter while user is typing?

Tags: powerbuilder

I need to know how to let the user filter while typing in a drop down datawindow in powerbuilder

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: http://anvil-of-time.com/wordpress/powerbuilder/powerbuilder-type-ahead-style-dropdown-datawindow-columns/

Answer (score 2):

In editchanged event of datawindow

Define field as datawindow child

```
DataWindowChild child1
Dw_1.getchild("sub_branch_id",child1)   // sub_branch_id name of column 
                                        // which is dropdowndatawindow
                                        // Displays name 
Child1.settransobject(sqlca)
If data = "" then
    Child1.setfilter("")
    Child1.filter()
    Child1.retrieve()
Else
    String fltr
    Fltr = "sub_branch_name " +"like"+"'%" +data+"%'" // filter on name
    Child1.accepttext()
    Child1.setfilter("")
    Child1.filter()
    Child1.setfilter(Fltr)
    Child1.filter()
End if
```